# Lightwell: what flooring material?

Tags: flooring

We have a lightwell on the 1st floor of our building (garage is right beneath) that receives a decent amount of rain.

What is an affordable material to use to update the floor?

[image]

The current floor does not seem to have been installed properly (is lumpy in places and water pools..and is discolored) and I can't tell what material it was to begin with.

Comment: Do you walk on this, other than to clean up trash? It appears to be more of a flat roof in a low position than a "floor" based on the present material and drain arrangement.

Comment: Is this a commercial floor? Typically commercial work is out of scope of the DIY SE. If it's a condo you may have to have the work done by your condo association.

Comment: it’s a condo, but it’s self managed so we need to figure this out ourselves..and no, this is not going to be generally used except to clean up occasionally

Comment: What's "affordable" for one may not be "affordable" for others. That's why shopping questions are off-topic. Besides, an "affordable" solution might not be water proof enough and could lead to building damage. Focus on "correct" materials - they'll pay off in the long run.

Comment: So, what you're looking for is flat roofing materials that can stand minimal foot traffic.

Comment: Off hand I would guess concrete for the the floor material.  A structural engineer should be  consulted since it will affect other people, but depending on the lumpiness, maybe cheaper grinding or raising it a bit to be level flat and have the proper slope for water draining.

Comment: What is the base colour of the floor, black or sandy?  I suspect its some kind of alkathene sheets. thermally joined.  They always bubble.

Answer (score 1):

So, It's a flat roof.

It looks like some variant on "torch down" or roll roofing, with a messy job of sealing it to the walls, and surface seams. Could be painted hot-mop asphalt (tar), but does not look quite like it.

If it's not leaking, I'd suggest tolerating a bit of puddles unless they are really causing a problem. Consider options and price out local contractors if not DIYing (or supplies and what you'll need to learn if DIYing), but don't rush to replace a watertight roof. If you want to make it look nicer, a can of roofing paint will address the color variance at far less expense than the full replacement. The full replacement will need to be addressed when it starts leaking, of course.

I would replace using tapered rigid foam to make a more positive drainage slope to the drain, and using EDPM rubber roofing, where a single sheet without seams can be obtained to cover the whole surface, and folded (not cut) into the corners up the edges, making the only places that will need special attention to sealing the penetration at the drain (most difficult) and the top edges of the sides where they attach to the walls (easier.)